# Recursion through List: Why is it returning None and giving separate lines?

Tags: python, recursion

I am figuring out a problem that goes through a list of strings, takes the first letter of each string and turns everything into an abbreviation of all the words in the list. So for example,

`print(recAbbrev(['central','processing','unit']))`

should return

`'CPU'`

Here is my code as of right now:

```
def recAbbrev(lst):
    'return a single string with the first character of all the strings in a list combined and capitalized.'
    if len(lst)==0:
        print('')
        return
    
    if len(lst)>0:
        if type(lst[0])==list:
            recAbbrev(lst[0])
        else:
            acronym = ""
            letter = ""
            letter = letter + lst[0][:1]
            letter = letter.upper()
            #lst.pop[0]
            acronym = acronym + letter
            print(acronym)  
            recAbbrev(lst[1:])
```

I am having two problems that I can't seem to understand with this code. First, I want my base case to return '' in the case of an empty list. Instead, it returns None. How can I work around this?
Here is my output:

```
Starting recAbbrev

None
C
P
U
```

This is a simple question, but how can I get everything to stay on one line? It seems like recursion is trying to keep me from doing this.

Comment: Why do you want a recursive solution? Is this supposed to work for nested lists too?

Comment: Just learning recursion right now and trying to understand how it works.

Comment: could you provide an example of what you expect for a nested list, e.g. `['central',['processing','unit']]`? Because right now none of the answers support that. And with your flat example, recursion is pointless, since you are better off with a solution like @Davide Madrisan's

Comment: In the case of a nested list, I would still want the same output, but I was not really considering those at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You are printing values and returning nothing. you have to modify you function:

```
def recAbbrev(lst):
    'return a single string with the first character of all the strings in a list combined and capitalized.'
    if len(lst)==0:
        return ''
    if len(lst)==1:
        return lst[0][0].upper()
    else:
        return lst[0][0].upper()+recAbbrev(lst[1:])
```

then test it:

```
lst = ['central','processing','unit']

recAbbrev(lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution can be the following, unless you must use a recursion because this is a homework:

```
def recAbbrev(lst):
    return "".join([w[0].upper() for w in lst])

lst = ['central','processing','unit']
print(recAbbrev(lst))
```

Output:

```
CPU
```

This works also if the list is empty and in this case it returns en empty string.

Answer (score -1):

`print` has a default `\n` character at the end of the printed string (see the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print)). Change `print(acronym)` to `print(acronym, end='')`

You are getting the `None` because you are printing `recAbbrev`, which has no return and therefore defaults to returning `None`. Just call `recAbbrev(['central','processing','unit'])`